# How can I use rem in susy?

Tags: susy-compass

after reading [this article](http://drublic.de/blog/rem-fallback-sass-less/), how can I use *rem* with susy?

Currently using *ems*, but it seems *rem* is the future :)

Also I notice that in version v1.0.5 there is support for *rem*, but I simply to understand how to integrate it to my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to it. All you have to do is change your settings. For example:

```
$column-width   : 4rem;
$gutter-width   : 1rem;
$grid-padding   : 1rem;
```

If you have created custom math anywhere, you may find other places that you have to switch from ems to rems. Just start with the grid settings, compile your code, and track down any errors.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Internet Explorer 9 supports _rem_, but versions before need fallback. Is it possible for _susy_ to add pixel fallback when using _rem_ or I need to do that manually.

Comment: You get that by default, but we do check the (not-yet-released) Compass `$rem-with-px-fallback` setting, if you ever want to turn it off.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the expected output of this is. Right now I have set my column and gutter wdiths to rem. The container outputs in rem as expected, with a pixel fall back.

I set some font sizes to rem, em, etc, but the output is the same as what I input. I guess I was expecting a pixel fallback for the font size also, so I didn't have to use the mixin in the original post (I like it, works well, just thought the susy mixin would do something similar).

Perhaps I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Susy doesn't do anything with font sizes. The change to container width is about the only time we interact directly with rem. There is a compass vertical-rhythms module that handles font-sizing, but rem support has only been added in the master branch and 0.13 alpha gems. I've been using the alpha for some time now, and it does exactly what you want.